# opposite of if condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to rewrite my if else statement so I skip the //do nothing part but I can't get my around to find the opposite of the if statement.

someone please help?!

```
if (decision.equals("repay")){                              
    String riskClass = null;
    if (doc.hasItem("riskclass")){
        riskClass = doc.getItemValueString("riskclass");
    }                                   

    if ( (null == riskClass) || (riskClass.equals("")) || (riskClass.equals("repay")) ){  
        //do nothing
    } else{                                 
        //do something
    }                               
}
```

Comment: Invert the conditions

Comment: `if (!((null == riskClass) || (riskClass.equals("")) || (riskClass.equals("repay"))){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply invert the condition. Try the snippet below.

```
if ( !((null == riskClass) || (riskClass.equals("")) || (riskClass.equals("repay"))) ){  
    //do something
}
```

Comment: sorry not the same result

Answer (score 2):

Another way to invert the check is invert individual conditions and replace `or`'s with `and`'s:

`if ( (null != riskClass) && (!riskClass.equals("")) && (!riskClass.equals("repay")) ){`

Another point:

Avoid call `equals` on variables passing constants: the constant will never be null. So in this particular case would be better write:

`if (!"repay".equals(riskClass) && !"".equals(riskClass))`

Comment: sadly `"repay".equals(rickClass)` doesn't work, because you have to invert it, to function like OP has intended. But then an empty string `""` and `null` would both be valid cases and would enter the *do something*-body and OP doesn't want that

Comment: the result is not the opposite?